# Encode video for streaming in Android using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

UPD: I guess I found the problem. For some reason, 1800x1080 video aren't playing while same vid resized to 800x480 with same set of encoding settings is working just fine. 
So the question is: why I couldn't play video with res. bigger than the size of my screen?

I'm trying to build a simple video-streaming app for android.

For the purpose of testing, I used this video http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4, and it worked fine.

However I miserably failed trying to prepare my own video for streaming.
I'm using FFmpeg & libx264 with the following line (last attempt):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict experimental <output>
```

Then I passed the output to `qt-faststart`, as some people suggested... No effect.

Here is the output of `ffmpeg -i` for my video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bbb_audio_h264.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2008-05-27 18:40:35
    encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5048 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 4605 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2008-05-27 18:40:35
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 440 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2008-05-27 18:40:35
      handler_name    :
```

And for the working one:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'big_buck_bunny.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
  Duration: 00:01:00.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 733 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 65 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 612 kb/s, 23.96 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : hint media handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : hint media handler
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong with the 1080p video?

Comment: The app reported with standard message "couldn't play the video".

Comment: Which app? The built-in video player? That won't be surprising, but depends on device and ROM.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I test on HTC Desire S, if it matters. The app uses MediaController & VideoView. I pretty new into development for android and used this article as a guide: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/

Comment: OK, so this is definitely the case. The fact that your device cannot play a 1080p baseline h264 stream is because ghe device manufacturer did not include such support. Other devices may play your stream even if their screens are ldss than 1080 pixels wide.

Comment: According to http://androidforums.com/htc-desire-s/341630-htc-desire-s-720p.html, your device can play 720p, even though the scree is only 800×480